# Add Image to parent item smartmenus

Tags: navigation

I have created a dropdown menu using smartmenus module, now I've got a design request asking me to add an image to each parent item. Here's the idea:
[image]

My first approach was to try with [Menu Items Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) and [Simple menu icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_menu_icons) but the images are not rendered. So I thought that this could be related to the menu module I've been working with so I tried with [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) and [Megamenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/we_megamenu). But again it didn't work.
I must say that Megamenu was the closest one but since it requires Font Awesome Icons I cannot use my designer's icons with this module.

My last try was to add a class to each parent menu link with [Menu Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) so I could add the images via CSS. The huge problem with this approach is that if I replace the parent menu item name with an image it will also appear on mobile making the menu to look massive.

Any ideas on how to add the images?

Comment: This is not a Drupal Problem, is this a pure CSS + HTML problem. Both, Menu Item Extras and Menu Link Attributes can be used for that, but no module will be able provide the design or responsive behavior for a custom theme out of the box. Since you've already made some progress with Menu Link Attributes, I'd suggest enhancing this solution with a CSS media query `@media (max-width: 767px) { .my_custom_nav_icon_class { display: none; } }`

Comment: @Hudri Thanks, I had the same idea but I was trying to find a different less cumbersome way, maybe with views or entity reference, not sure. Just exploring

Comment: Btw, to deactivate my class the media query I'm currently using is:

`@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {.my_class_name { 
    content: '';
    height: 100% !important;
}}`